# Out of memory for large scatter plot in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, eps, matlab2tikz

I have exported four Matlab plots with matlab2tikz to tikz. Each plot has 10000 scatter points. When I try to use it in LaTeX I'm getting an out of memory error. I have also converted the figures to eps but the eps files are very big and take long to load when viewing the PDF. Also the font size is very small in the eps files.

How can I solve this issue? Can I perhaps send somebody my four tikz files for e.g. conversion to PDF (or other format)?

Edit: I have uploaded the files here: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AlkQuYgB1McYiDeZiTLqyJKanjlD

Comment: Did you try to compile with lualatex?

Comment: @mirkom Yes, I'm also getting an out of memory error.

Comment: @mirkom Could you take a look or do you have any suggestions?

Comment: OneDrive requires me to sign in, but I don't have an account (and I can't see a way to skip this).

Comment: I encounter the same problem as @ManuelSchmidt

Comment: @machinery I've OneDrive but I cannot see any document right now

Comment: You may also share the `.mat` file with the array you'd like to plot